# Python: smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, imap, smtplib

I'm attempting to create a program that reads the unread emails and responds to the send with the usage of auto-reply which would be triggered by the use of certain phrases. I'm doing this in Mac OSX in Visual Code. I'm able to connect to IMAP and SMTP but then I get the following error,
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first.

I tried to use an exception that was part of the smtplib which should be raised if the SMTP server disconnects, but it doesn't do anything.

```py
def smtp_init():

    print("Initializing STMP . . .",end = '')
    global s
    s = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver,smtpserverport)
    status_code = s.starttls()[0]
    if status_code is not 220:
        raise Exception('Starting tls failed: '+ str(status_code))
    status_code = s.login(radr,pwd)[0]
    if status_code is not 235:
        raise Exception('SMTP login failed: '+ str(status_code))
    print("Done. ")


except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:

        smtp_init() 
        continue
```

The expected results would be to have the program in a loop checking the emails and responding to them if they have a phrase that corresponds to the auto-reply.